# Text in react native is truncated wrongly when fontSize is big

Tags: android, react-native, text, expo, truncate

When I'm using fontSize greater than 20 and adding numberOfLines={1} in the Text to truncate the valeu, the **three dots are cut off**, as shown in the picture below. This problem is not happening in iOS, just in Android.

[image]

It seems that is also related to the size of the words.

In the picture below, I'm using fontSize: 20 and the problem is not happening.

[image]

Here is a snack: https://snack.expo.io/tR47ZU0Zz

Things which I have tried:

- Add empty space in the end of the text;
- Change fontFamily to Roboto;
- Add textBreakStrategy with simple to Text;

Expo SDK Version: 38

Could anyone help me?

Comment: now what do you want to do...if you increase font size then it will definately looks like that....you can add white space by using paddingRight or wrap <Text> component in <View> then provide paddingRight to <View>...

Comment: @SavinderSingh, I have already tried that, but the three dots have been still cutted off

Comment: I know this issue is pretty old, but were you able to fix it?